# How to use this sencha touch images in our app?

Tags: javascript, android, image, cordova, sencha-touch

How to get inbuild sencha touch images and what are the images class names in sencha touch. How to call that images in sencha touch css ?

i got only few names of that some icons in that images. So how to access remaining icons ?

[Check this link to see that sencha touch image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwE7EGp9sZvmdUpNaTVnaXNzWEU/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "iconCls" property to set an icon.

```
xtype: 'button',
height: 38,
iconCls: 'search',
iconMask: true,
align: 'left',
itemId:'audioSearchbtnid'
```

Check out the kitchen sink example [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/#demo/icons) to find more icons.

You can find the icons in Sencha_Root_Folder\resources\themes\images\default.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Thats what i want.